# loopback automatically deletes AccessToken after User.update or User.upsert

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Its occurring randomly.
After upsert or update loopback automatically deletes that users accessToken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback updateAttributes setting password deletes token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612151/loopback-updateattributes-setting-password-deletes-token)

Comment: This is because of the new behavior where I explained in the answer of the question I have linked.